# Tumblr API: how to retrieve title and id of all text posts

Tags: tumblr

I want to pull all the text posts ever made to display a list of links.  I just need the post title and id.

This form of url

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{mydomain}/posts/text?api_key={key}
```

retrieves all the data for the first 20 or so entries.  Is there a way to

1. Just get the title and id to reduce the amount of data returned (the
   body element can be large).
2. Get more than 20 entries with one request (since the amount of data is now smaller the hit on the tumblr server is reduced and I'd like it to do more).

Without a solution the only way I can think of to display a table of contents for all posts is to query and retrieve all posts: including their body elements.

Comment: 1. I don't believe you can do this because the request system isn't setup to send parts. 2. You can change the limit by using `&limit=yourlimit` in the request. *Side note*: you may be interested in looking at [some script I made](https://github.com/ZachSaucier/tumblr-book/blob/master/TumblrBookScript.js) for more detail on how to strip what you need

Comment: Just to add to what @ZachSaucier said. 1) The data is sent as json, so the body element size shouldn't pose a size issue. 2) You would need to make multiple requests to get more than 20 posts. Use `offset`.

Comment: Thanks Zach and Mike.  I think you are correct about the way the API works. It just seems a shame to make multiple requests to get all postings (for the side menu) even if the user just wants to see one post (e.g. retrieve one post by id).   Oh well,  I may be trying to achieve premature optimization.  Perhaps, it will just be fine to make all these requests. Time will tell.